# Similar matrices of rank 1

Tags: linear-transformations, matrix-rank, trace

I am able to prove that two matrices of rank 1 are similar if and only if they have the same trace.

But, my proof is long and complicated. In particular, I use the fact that the union of non-trivial subspaces can't be equal to the whole space.
My proof goes like this

1. I prove the equivalent result for endormorphims of $E$, let's call them $f$ and $g$.
2. I write $f = a\cdot e$ and $g = b\cdot f$, with $a, b\in E^*$ and $e,f\in E$.
3. We can assume $a, b \neq 0$
4. Then, I write $E = k.e_a\oplus \ker(a)$ and $E = k.e_b\oplus \ker(b)$. With $a(e_a)=1$ and $b(e_b)=1$.
5. Then, I decompose $e$ in $k.e_a\oplus \ker(a)$. It is $\lambda_a \cdot e_a + x_a$. And same for $b$. We can prove that $\text{tr}\ u = \lambda_a$.
6. Etc, etc. I already feel at this point that the proof is too complicated. Then, I build the automorphim $\phi$ by doing $e_a \to e_b$ and $\ker a \to \ker b$. But, we need to have also $\phi(x_a) = x_b$.
7. So, we need $x_a \neq 0$ and $x_b \neq 0$. We do this by taking $x_a$ and $x_b$ not being eigen vectors of $u$ and $v$. This where I use the result about the union...

It all seems too complicated. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Does equivalence of matrices mean $A = P \cdot B \cdot Q^{-1}$ to you or $A = P \cdot B \cdot P^{-1}$?

Comment: I mean similarity, hence $PBP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible Jordan Normal forms for a rank $1$ matrix are

$$J_1= \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    c & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline
    0  &  0 &\cdots &0\\
    {\vdots} & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
  \end{array}\right) 
J_2= \left(\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
    0 & 1 & 0&\cdots  & 0 \\ 
    0  &  0 & 0 &\cdots &0\\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots &0\\
    {\vdots} & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
  \end{array}\right)$$

This makes the claim almost trivial: if $A$, $B$ are two rank one matrices, then
$$\text{tr}(A)=c_{A},\qquad \text{tr}(B)=c_{B} $$
where $c_A$, $c_B$ are either $0$ or the only non-zero eigenvalues of the two matrices. If $c_A=c_B$, the two matrices have the same normal form and hence are similar, otherwise they are not.

---

Without using the Jordan decomposition, one can notice that the kernel of a rank one operator $A$ has dimension $n-1$. Consider a basis of $\ker A=\langle v_2,\ldots, v_n \rangle$ and a linearly independent vector $v_1\not \in \ker A$. We can visualize the kernel of a matrix as the eigenspace of eigenvalue $0$. If there exists one non-zero eigenvalue, algebraic and geometric multeplicity of $0$ coincide. Let $c$ be $A$'s only non-zero eigenvalue. For dimensionality restrictions, we know that $c$'s eigenspace $V_c$ has dimension one. Since eigenspaces relative to different eigenvalues are in direct sum,
$$V=\ker A \oplus V_c$$
implying that $A$'s matrix is exactly $J_1$. This shows that if $\text{tr}(A)=c_A,~\text{tr}(B)=c_B$, with $c_A,c_B\neq 0$ then $A$ is similar to $B$ if and only if they have the same trace.

Now, if $A$ has only $0$ as an eigenvalue, then $A$'s characteristic polynomial is $x^n$. This shows that if $A,B$ are two rank one matrices such that $\text{tr}(A)=0,~ \text{tr}(B) \neq 0$ they are not similar, because their characteristic polynomials are different.

If $\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(B)=0$, the matrices are similar to two of the following kind:

$$A'= \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline
    a_1  &  0 &\cdots &0\\
    {\vdots} & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
    a_n & 0 & \cdots & 0 
  \end{array}\right)
B'= \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline
    b_1  &  0 &\cdots &0\\
    {\vdots} & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
    b_n & 0 & \cdots & 0 
  \end{array}\right)
$$

I cannot think of an elementary method to show that they are similar at the moment, I'll edit the post if something comes to mind.

Comment: I am looking for a proof that does not use Jordan reduction.

Comment: @Colas I'll edit my post accordingly. Jordan theory is not indispensable in this case, but provides a quick tool to reduce your claim to triviality. There is no actual use of generalized eigenvectors, but only of simple ones because the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: The matrix is not always diagonalizable. But let me see your answer!

Comment: Your proof works if the matrix has a non-zero eigen value, but it is not always the case. Think of nilpotent matrix of rank 1.

Comment: In dimension 2, think of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You're right indeed. I'll see what I can do to fix it. This basically happens when all Jordan blocks have eigenvalue zero, but one has dimension 2.

Answer (score 1):

Note that two similar matrix have the same trace. Indeeed if$A$ and $B$ are similar then exist an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $$A=Q^{-1}BQ$$ and taking trace in both sides we obtain $$tr A=tr(Q^{-1}QB)=tr A=tr B$$ If a matrix has rank $1$ for the theorem of nullity+rank the $\ker$ associated to two matrix has dimension $n-1$. Therefore you can choose a new basis $(v_1,.....,v_{n-1},v_n)$ with the first $n-1$ vectors that belongs to $\ker$ of two matrix while $v_n$ belongs to $im f$. In this new basis the two matrix are similar to: $$P= \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
    c & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline
    *  &  0 &\cdots &0\\
    {\vdots} & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
    * & 0 & \cdots & 0 
  \end{array}\right)$$ if the trace is equal then are similar.

## Edit

Note that a matrix of rank $1$  and trace$\neq 0$ is diagonalizable and similar to $$J= \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
     c & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline
     0  &  0 &\cdots &0\\
     {\vdots} & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
     0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
   \end{array}\right)$$
Therefore if two matrix have the same trace are similar to same diagonal matrix and they are similar

Comment: It is false that you can find a basis $v_i$ where the two matrices are or the given form.

Comment: No it's true...

Comment: Note that a matrix of rank 1 and trace$\neq 0$ is diagonalizable and similar $$J= \left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
     c & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline
     0  &  0 &\cdots &0\\
     {\vdots} & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
     0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
   \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: False : In dimension 2, think of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But $tr =0$....

Comment: Yes you're right. I misread your comment, sorry.